# How to find application builder in APEX 5 to build first application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I got started with oracle apex 5 and lately finished apex installation, I want to start building first application.  I found in apex documentation that I should start with application builder but I didn't find it in my environment.
When I login to APEX, the environment appears as in this image:

[image: APEX environment screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are logged into Oracle Application Express Administration Services (apex admin short) and not Application Express Workspace.

Apex Admin is the place where you manage Oracle Application Express instances and work-spaces and a workspace is an area within the Oracle Application Express development environment where developers can create applications.

If you just finish installing APEX I suggest you go over [this configuration tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/start_login.htm#HTMDB01006) to configure the workspace and be able to build applications.

Answer (score 2):

Cristian is correct, but this may help more:

You should go to this URL: http://localhost:8080/apex/ .  You have to know the name of one of the workspaces you created, and a user with Admin or Developer role.  These Workspace users can be created in the apex_admin site ( http://localhost:8080/apex/apex_admin/ ), under "Manage Workspaces" / "Manage Developers and Users".  Also, Admin users of each Workspace can create new users once you get in.